# Embedding matplotlib graph on pygt window in picture format

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt

I have a problem with converting matplotlib graph into image and embedding it on window in PyQt. I use the following code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg

class WindowPixML(QtWidgets.QWidget):
   def __init__(self,figure):
      super().__init__()
      self.canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(figure)       
      self.canvas.draw()
      size = self.canvas.size()
      #size = self.size()
      width, height = size.width(), size.height()
      #print(int(width),int(height))
      self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(int(width), int(height))
      painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.pixmap)
      self.canvas.render(painter)
      painter.end()         
      self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
      self.label.resize(size.width(), size.height())
      self.label.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)     
      self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
      self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)     
      self.label.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
      #self.label.setScaledContents(True)
      self.label.installEventFilter(self)
      self.totalLayout= QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
      self.totalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
      self.setLayout(self.totalLayout)    
      self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('images/download.jpg')) 
      self.setWindowTitle("Model Validation")
     
   def eventFilter(self, source, event):
      if (source is self.label and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Resize):
         self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap.scaled(
         self.label.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio,QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation))
      return super(WindowPixML, self).eventFilter(source, event)
```

but always get the image which is smaller than it should be to fill all space in the window see the picture

[Graph as an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZQpc.png)

If I embed without converting the job is done perfectly see the image and the code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg

class WindowScoreML(QtWidgets.QWidget):
   def __init__(self,figure):
      super().__init__()
      self.canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(figure)   
      self.totalLayout= QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
      self.totalLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)
      self.setLayout(self.totalLayout) 
      self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('images/download.jpg')) 
      self.setWindowTitle("Score Test")
```

[Graph which is not an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6xgv.png)

but it takes a lot of memory if the graph is linked to the big data table
that's why I wanted to convert the graph into a picture and to embed on a window

Please help me to adjust the previous code to get the image to fill all space in the window, if it is possible of course

Thanks a lot to everybody!

My purpose is to decrease amount of memory when embedding graphs on pyqt window.